# How to make Panel as a Card Layout in Visual Basic? (compared to Java)

Tags: java, vb.net, layout, panel

Sorry, I'm asking this kind of question.
Because I found the Panel in Visual Basic gave me different treatment
not just what Java (environment) gave me.

Any way, I didn't get any Panel configuration for making a Card Layout treatment 
In Visual Basic. Is that true?

If you confuse what Card Layout (from Java) that I'm saying now, hopefully this story could give you a clear idea:

> User has a Panel. This Panel containing Two Pages. First Pages,  The
>   Calculator page, The Next page is Summary page. But these pages are contained in a single Form. So a user is just moving from one page to
>   another from this single Form only.

I just wondering how to make it in VB.
What's the solutions for making that kind of app anyway?

Answer (score 4):

I think what your looking for is the [`TabControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984280%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). When you are looking at the toolbox in Visual Studio, look for it in the *"Containers"* group.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmmm... yeah, the functionality is from "TABControl" But,
I just wondering how to use my own button for navigating from one page to another. Because TABControl automatically gave us a Button to be clicked, right? How to use my own button (another button) as navigation instead of the TABControl's button? :D

Comment: @gumuruh - The Tab control does not give you any buttons.  It is just a container for tab pages.  You will have to provide the contents of the pages.

Comment: @gumuruh - Use TabControl.SelectedIndex or TabControl.SelectedTab to move between the pages programmatically.